# $\|x\otimes y\| \leq \|x\| \|y\|$

Tags: linear-algebra, banach-spaces, tensor-products, banach-algebras

I am reading the book Introduction to tensor products of Banach spaces by Ryan. In chapter 2, page 15, author said to define a norm on $X\otimes Y=$ span $\{x\otimes y: x \in X, y \in Y\}$ , it is natural to require that $\|x\otimes y\| \leq \|x\| \|y\|$ for all x in X and y in Y.

I don't understand why we need this  requirement. May be it is obvious but it is not so clear to me. I am new in this area. Any hints or suggestions would be appreciated. Thank you very much.

$x\otimes y$ is a linear map from $B(X\times Y)$ to $\mathbb{R}$ such that $(x\otimes y) (A) = A(x, y) $

$B(X\times Y)$ is space of all linear maps from $X\times Y$ to $\mathbb{R}$

Comment: If you've studied abstract algebra, then it's typical to see that the definition of a norm includes $|xy| \leq |x||y|$. I'd also take a look at https://mathworld.wolfram.com/NormedRing.html

Comment: For example, if you consider the case $X=\mathbb{R}^n$, $Y=\mathbb{R}^m$ and you use the euclidean norm for vectors and matrices then $$|x \otimes y|^2= \sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{j=1}^m x_i^2 y_j^2 \leq |x|^2|y|^2$$ with the identification between $\mathbb{R}^{n \times m}$ and $\mathbb{R}^n \otimes \mathbb{R}^m$ given by $xy^T=x \otimes y$

Comment: Actually in this case the equality holds, but if you consider the operator norm for matrices you get only the desired inequality